# how can i build procedure to return how many times words appear in each row in sql

Tags: mysql

example 
table name with column text (fulltext)

```
id text
1   Lorem Ipsum has **Dani** been the industry's standard dummy
2   scrambled it to **Mike** make a type specimen book
3   popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not **John** simply random text
4   popular **Dani** random text
5   popular belief, Lorem **Dani** simply random text 
6   popular belief, Lorem **Dani** simply random text simply text **Dani** random text
7   scram **Mike** make a type specimen book tess test
```

the words i search (Dani , Mike, John)
i want to build procedure that return

```
text_search number_time_show_in_each_row 
Dani           4
Mike           2
John           1
```

Comment: WELCOME mUS90, Are you using sql server, postgres, Oracle or...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for I beleive
NB: the results should give 5 Dani because, id 1 has 1, id 4 has 1, id 5 has 1 and id 6 has 2.

```
text_search number_time_show_in_each_row 
Dani           5
Mike           2
John           1
```

If you are using sql server you can use len for length, if postgres, use length instead of len. Oracle uses length too. So depending on your sql plateforme you just change the word len to the one corresponding and the query below will work

```
;with cte as
(
select 1 AS id  ,'Lorem Ipsum has **Dani** been the industry''s standard dummy' as text
union select 2   ,'scrambled it to **Mike** make a type specimen book'
union select 3   ,'popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not **John** simply random text'
union select 4  ,'popular **Dani** random text'
union select 5   ,'popular belief, Lorem **Dani** simply random text' 
union select 6   ,'popular belief, Lorem **Dani** simply random text simply text **Dani** random text'
union select 7   ,'scram **Mike** make a type specimen book tess test'
)
select text_search, sum(OCcurrence) as number_time_show_in_each_row 
from
(
    select 'Dani' as text_search  ,(len(text)-len(replace(text, 'Dani','')))/len('Dani') as OCcurrence from cte
    union all
    select 'Mike',(len(text)-len(replace(text, 'Mike','')))/len('Mike') from cte
    union all
    select 'John',(len(text)-len(replace(text, 'John','')))/len('John') from cte
) a group by text_search
```

***Below is a solution including a stored procedure***

```
create table mytable(id int, text text);
insert into mytable ( id, text)
select id, text from
(
select 1 AS id  ,'Lorem Ipsum has **Dani** been the industry''s standard dummy' as text
union select 2   ,'scrambled it to **Mike** make a type specimen book'
union select 3   ,'popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not **John** simply random text'
union select 4  ,'popular **Dani** random text'
union select 5   ,'popular belief, Lorem **Dani** simply random text' 
union select 6   ,'popular belief, Lorem **Dani** simply random text simply text **Dani** random text'
union select 7   ,'scram **Mike** make a type specimen book tess test'
) a;

CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllOccurrence()
BEGIN
    select text_search, sum(Occurrence) as number_time_show_in_each_row 
    from
    (
        select 'Dani' as text_search  ,(length(text)-length(replace(text, 'Dani','')))/length('Dani') as OCcurrence from mytable
        union all
        select 'Mike',(length(text)-length(replace(text, 'Mike','')))/length('Mike') from mytable
        union all
        select 'John',(length(text)-length(replace(text, 'John','')))/length('John') from mytable
    ) a group by text_search;
END;
```

Comment: Thank Zip, but i looking for build sql procedure

Comment: what is your sql plateform Mus90?